# Как сделать часть текста в String файле большими буквами . а именно https://bitinfocharts.com

Tags: java, android

```
 <string name="activity4_button1">НАЗАД</string>
    <string name="activity4_textView1"
        >Данные страницы курсов взяты с сайта:
        \n      https://bitinfocharts.com
```

Comment: Может с помощью CSS?

Comment: напечатать нужный текст БОЛЬШИМИ БУКВАМИ ?

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть несколько вариантов как это сделать.

1. Если ваша строка статична, то самое простое и очевидное - написать нужный текст большими буквами.
2. Это использовать HTML текст. Это не очень удобно и не очень часто используется в Android.
3. Если вы имеете динамическую строку, то используйте Spannable и задавайте программно формат текста. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable