# Как сделать часть текста в String файле ЖИРНЫМ шрифтом . а именно https://bitinfocharts.com

Tags: java, android

```
    <string name="activity4_textView1"
        >Данные страницы курсов взяты с сайта:
        \n      https://bitinfocharts.com
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458549/177345

Comment: В прошлом вопросе 2 из 3 ответов которые я вам писал решают вашу проблему. Незачем создавать одинаковые вопросы с разницей в одно слово. Для этого можно просто редактировать старый или общаться в комментариях

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать часть текста в String файле большими буквами . а именно https://bitinfocharts.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092005/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-string-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-https-biti)

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть нужную строку в `<html><strong>строка</strong></html>`.

Comment: Опишите детальнее как это должен сделать автор вопроса.  А лучше с примером на его же разметке.